# Is the function $f$ continuous at $(0,0)$??

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

> Let $\mathbb R^2$ endowed with the euclidean norm $||\cdot ||_2$.
>
> Let $f : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$. Assume that there exists two real-valued sequences $\{x_n\}_{n>0} $ and $\{y_n\}_{n>0} $ such that $(x_n, y_n) \to (0, 0)$ as $n \to \infty$ and $f(x_n, y_n)$ does not tend to $f(0, 0)$ as $n \to \infty$.
>
> Show that $f$ is not continuous at $(0, 0)$.

My attempt:

I used the definition of continuity:

Def: $f$ is continuous at $a$ in $\mathbb R$ if and only if for all $\varepsilon$ > $0$, there exists $\delta$ > $0$ such that if $|x-a| < \delta$, then $|f(x) - f(a)| < \varepsilon$.

Here we have that $|(x_n, y_n)-(0,0)|<\delta$, but this did not imply that $|f(x_n, y_n)-f(0,0)| < \varepsilon$.

And thus $f$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$.

Is my attempt correct? Any other better suggestions please? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clarity is missing in the proof. Suppose, if possible, $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$. You have to say that you have $|(x_n,y_n)-(0,0)|<\delta$ **for $n$ sufficiently large**. Then you get $|f(x_n,y_n)-f(0,0)|<\epsilon$ for $n$ sufficiently large. Since $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary we get $f(x_n,y_n) \to f(0,0)$ contradicting the hypothesis.

Comment: Ohh okay, yes that's much better, thank you!

Comment: And is this proof by contradiction sufficient? Are there any missing details?

Comment: @JOJO Nothing is missing . This is the complete proof.